# Jmeter 3.2 Report Generation issue

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to generate an HTML report from Jmeter where the input is in a .CSV file.

I am not getting an error but the HTML file is not being generated.

Comment: "Please find below Log file and User.property file" - I do not see anything here.

Comment: How do you execute jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you follow pre requisites described in reference documentation and read this [tutorial](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/) by one of JMeter developers :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements

Most common mistakes :

- very short test of few seconds to 5 minutes
- checking generate parent sampler